# Using radar to measure ocean waves along the shoreline

Tags: oceanography, waves, radar

What radar technology would be best to measure the attributes of ocean waves near (under 2k distance) the shoreline?

Comment: you can find all of the information you need here https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-3-altimetry/overview/geophysical-measurements/significant-wave-height

Comment: this is the product from the satelite data https://earth.nullschool.net/#current/ocean/primary/waves/overlay=significant_wave_height/orthographic=4.17,61.00,1125 a color coded map showing wave hight,blue means small waves and red is big waves.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like the [CODAR SeaSonde](https://codar.com/seasonde/).